# Running Django Framework in SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: django, simplehttpserver

Is it possible to set up Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` to serve Django apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html):

> This class serves files from the current directory and below, directly
>   mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests.

So SimpleHTTPServer only serves static files from a directory and is therefore unable to execute arbitrary code to provide response.

Why would you do that?

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up finding `python manage.py runserver` shortly after this.  Doh.